# TYPO3 and locallang.xml texts being displayed as "Array" instead of text inside fluid template

Tags: localization, typo3

I am having some problems regarding the use of `locallang.xml`
I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
    <meta type="array">
        <type>module</type>
        <description>Language labels for BE plugin</description>
    </meta>
    <data type="array">
        <languageKey index="default" type="array">
            <label index="mlang_testtext">This is a test text to be translated</label>
        </languageKey>
        <languageKey index="es" type="array">
            <label index="mlang_testtext">Esto es un texto de prueba para ser traducido</label>
        </languageKey>
    </data>
</T3locallang>
```

Inside fluid template, I can use

```
<f:translate key="mlang_testtext" />
```

But If I try

```
{LLL:mlang_testtext}
```

All I get is the text `Array`

Also, if I try both of them inside a partial template, neither of those ones works.

EDIT: There are places where I can't use `<f:translate .../>` for example in button labels so I need the other form working too

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/TranslateViewHelper.php` for sample of correct inline usage, so for an example setting your label as a default value of the input field would look like this:

```
<f:form.textfield name="myTextBox" value="{f:translate(key: 'mlang_testtext')}" />
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something in a config, since the example you provided just outputs empty label :(

Comment: Ouch, I forgot to delete cache. It seems to work, many thanks!